# Abstract/Virtual Classes: Displaying Color Property in string format inside a Multiline textBox

Tags: c#

I am currently learning to work with `abstract` classes and `virtual`. I created a simple form that generates the names of animals, color, and the sound they make. Everything seems to work right except for color display property. The results are being displayed in a multiline textBox. Is there a way to display the result with only the color name instead of this format `Color [DarkGray]`?

Result when button clicked:

```
Betty is a Color [DarkGray] horse with four legs and runs very fast that goes neigh! neigh!!
```

The desired result:

```
Betty is a Dark Gray horse with four legs and runs very fast that goes neigh! neigh!!
```

**CODE**

```
namespace farm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public abstract class Animal
        {
            protected string the_name;
            protected string the_type;
            protected Color the_color;
            protected string features;

            public virtual string speaks()
            {
                return "";
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                string s = the_name + " is a " + the_color + " " + the_type + " with " + features + " that goes " + speaks();
                return s;
            }
        }

public class Horse : Animal
        {
            public Horse(string new_name, Color new_color)
            {
                the_name = new_name;
                the_color = new_color;
                the_type = "horse";
                features = "four legs and runs very fast";

            }

            public override string speaks()
            {
                return "neigh! neigh!!";
            }

        }

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Horse horse1 = new Horse("Topaz", Color.DarkGray);
            textBox1.AppendText(horse1.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is not related to abstract and virtual. You asking how to get Color name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in your ToString method, use:

```
the_color.Name
```

Or better still, if you want to have a string with whitespace in where the string contains upper case characters, e.g. DarkGray => Dark Gray, you could define an extension like this

```
public static class ColorExtensions
{
    public static string GetColorString(this Color color)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(char c in color.Name.ToCharArray())
        {
            if (char.IsUpper(c))
                sb.Append(' ');

            sb.Append(c);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}
```

and call it like this

```
the_color.GetColorString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Name` property of color to get the human readable name.

```
string s = the_name + " is a " + the_color.Name + " " + the_type + " with " + features + " that goes " + speaks(); 
return s;
```

Often times it helps to look up the Namespace on MSDN and look through the available methods and properties. In this case, you could review the [Color Structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14w97wkc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN and you'll find in the Properties section a property for [Color.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.name%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> This method returns either the user-defined name of the color, if the
>   color was created from a name, or the name of the known color. For
>   custom colors, the RGB value is returned.